# Use existing django users with Auth0

Tags: python, django, auth0, django-users, social-auth-app-django

I'm trying to connect Auth0 with django, but I want to use the users that already exists in the system. I want them to sync by their email, but Auth0 creates new users.

I used the Auth0 documentation to do so.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/django/01-login

Comment: I think this solves your problem. https://auth0.com/docs/users/configure-automatic-migration-from-your-database

Comment: I resolved it with this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304729/django-authentication-new-user-created-unnecessarily-auth0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the How To Ask a Good Question page for details on how to best help us help you.